# CSS with ASP.NET MVC Razor View. How to set page to device width? Meta tag is not working

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have total 4 view pages, One page used as main page and the remaining 3 are loading to main page with the help of partial view. Everything works well. But the thing is I am unable to adjust the page for device width. Even though I have added  tag with View Port attribute. How can I achieve this?

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features Try this

Answer (score 1):

To make sure I understand you correctly, you want to dynamically resize the page based on the size of the device, right? I do not believe you have the ability to override user settings when they initially visit your page; however, you can get references to the browser height and width using `$(window).height() and $(window).width()`, respectively.

Also, you can set the size of a new page if a user triggers some event.

```
window.open("https://google.com", "", "width=700,height=700");
```